# How can I see the options passed to tomcat8 while starting?

Tags: tomcat

I have installed tomcat8 on Debian9 using sudo apt install tomcat8.

In the file /etc/init.d/tomcat8

I modified this line:-

JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true"

to

JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx512M -Xms64M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"

My query is : How do I check that tomcat8 was really started with these parameters ? Is there a way to check this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

```
$ apt-get install visualvm
$ visualvm
```

and then select your running Tomcat JVM instance. In the [overview tab](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/visualvm/visualvm.java.net.backup/master/www/overview_tab.html) you'll see all JVM arguments passed to the JVM when tomcat started.